# vsto excel workbook unit testing

Tags: vsto

I am creating unit test cases for VSTO excel workbook project. I have below method in the thisworkbook.cs file.

```
public void ValidateOnOpen(ICredentials credential)
    {
        if (credential != null)
        {
            WorkbookSettings.WindowsCredentials = credential;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Save(); 
            Application.Quit();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

when i am created unit test case for this method, the code looks like below.

```
 [TestMethod()]
    public void ValidateOnOpenTest()
    {
        Factory factory = null;                         
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = null; 
        ThisWorkbook target = new ThisWorkbook(factory, serviceProvider); 
        ICredentials credential = null; 
        target.ValidateOnOpen(credential);           
    }
```

please can you tell me how i can initialize the below line with Factory and Iserviceprovider

```
ThisWorkbook target = new ThisWorkbook(factory, serviceProvider);
```

Thanks,
Suresh